# How to run this command in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, shell, command

I am asked to execute a programme by using command prompt.

the command is :

```
E:\Program Files\SAPHome\SAPPrivateRun\9.4\jre\bin\java.exe -jar E:\Thirdparty\sap113.jar
```

however, whenever i paste this in windows command prompt, i am getting error:
[image: Image below]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Put the java.exe path in "quotes"

Answer (score 0):

Try by enclosing path with doublequotes ". e.g. :

"E:\Program Files\SAPHome\SAPPrivateRun\9.4\jre\bin\java.exe"